# Find the roots of $x = \tanh(\beta x + \beta h)$

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered the equation $x = \tanh(\beta x + \beta h),$ whereby $\beta, h$ are constants. We look for the set of roots for small and large values of the parameter $\beta.$ The problem I have is the fact that $x$ is both in the argument as well as the function itself. The book says that for small values of $\beta,$ the equation has a unique root, while for large values of $\beta$ one gets multiple roots or zeros. I do not see how these conclusions on the number of roots are made. We know that $\tanh$ takes its roots for an argument that vanishes. In this case it means, $\beta x + \beta h = 0.$ Since $\beta$ is assumed to be either small or large, we assume $\beta \neq 0.$ It follows that $x = -h.$ But since in general $h\neq 0,$ this leads to a contradiction, $0 = x = -h.$ Can somebody tell how many roots does the equation above have depending on the parameter $\beta$ ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case $0<\beta<1$: we can see $x=\tanh(\beta x+\beta h)$ as a fixed point problem $x=g_\beta(x)$ with $g_\beta$ infinitely many times differentiable. We have that
$$\vert g_\beta'(x)\vert=\beta\vert \operatorname {sech}^2(\beta x+\beta h)\vert\leq \beta<1,\ x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Then, $x=\tanh(\beta x+\beta h)$ has a unique solution for $\beta<1$.

Case $\beta\gg1$: the number of zeroes also depends on h. Graphically, $\tanh(\beta x+\beta h)$ comes from translating $\tanh x$ horizontally $\vert h\vert$ units to the right if $h<0$ or to the left if $h>0$, and then compressing the graph of $\tanh (x+h)$ horizontally by a factor of $\beta$. For instance:

[[image: <span class=]$\beta=20,h=-1,\text{ with desmos }$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua45M.png)

Then, graphically, we should see one or more intercepts, depending on $\beta$ and $h$. To prove that there is at least one intercept we can work with the fixed problem $x=\tanh(\beta x+\beta h)=g_\beta(x)$ again, but this time we choose an interval for $x$ on which

$$\vert g_\beta'(x)\vert=\beta\vert \operatorname {sech}^2(\beta x+\beta h)\vert<1$$

to apply the fixed point Theorem on that interval. It is possible to find such interval because

$$\lim_{\vert x\vert\to\infty}\operatorname {sech}(x)=0.$$

Comment: Do you mean by $\tan$ rather the tangent hyperbolicus, $\tanh$ ?

Comment: It's $\tanh$ in all the above. I just changed it. I think that's how it was written before somebody else edited it.

Comment: Thanks. I do not see though, how for large $\beta$ there could me more than one intercept, the fixed point problem providing a unique solution. I though first that $\tanh$ is periodical, but this is false. Can you elaborate little bit in your argument to show that for large $\beta$ there can be more than one root of the equation ?

Comment: I can among different values for $h$ and $\beta,$ find at most 2 roots for $h=0.$

Comment: Hi @user996159. Sure! In the case $\beta$ is large we have a unique solution on an interval on which $\vert\operatorname{sech}(\beta x+\beta h)\vert\ll1 $. This uniqueness does not necessarily imply uniqueness on the whole real line. Finally, for instance, when $h=0$ and $\beta=100$ there are three intercepts: $(-1,-1)$, $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.